# How to show django filter form elements seperately

Tags: django, django-filter

I am new to django and using the material online I was able to build a filtering form using django-filter. I am able to show the filter on the html page using a format as below:

```
{{filtergroup.form}}
```

This does show the filter correctly and worked well on the page however I wanted to check if there is a way to show individual elements / filters in the form separately so that I can arrange the filters and format easily. Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: Any advise? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field, say, author, you can access it like this :
{{ filter.form.author }}